# Insert rows into table based on checkboxes in a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio (asp.net and c#). My Repeater displays a checkbox and label for each row that I want. Now I want to take the ones that are checked and insert new rows into my table.

Everything seems okay, but when I check my db, no rows are added.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSetFormFields]
    @FormId int,
    @EventId int,
    @ColumnName nvarchar(255),
    @Visible bit,
    @ColumnOrder int,
    @DisplayName nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO FormField(FormId, EventId, ColumnName, Visible, ColumnOrder, DisplayName)
    VALUES (@FormId, @EventId, @ColumnName, @Visible, @ColumnOrder, @DisplayName)
END
```

C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        //Insert text into db
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
        {
            //If checked, visible = true
            foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in Repeater1.Items)
            {
                int i = 1;
                CheckBox chkbx = rpItem.FindControl("Checkbox1") as CheckBox;
                Label lbl = rpItem.FindControl("lblTest") as Label;

                if (chkbx.Checked)
                {
                    sqlCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd2.CommandText = "spSetFormFields";

                    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
                    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
                    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lbl.Text;
                    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@DisplayName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lbl.Text;
                    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@Visible", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
                    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@ColumnOrder", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = i;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not executing the query anywhere do `sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();` after you've passed in your params. Also open your connection after you've passed the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your Parameters and execute your query. Like so:

```
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Clear(); // Add This line
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lbl.Text;
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@DisplayName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lbl.Text;
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@Visible", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@ColumnOrder", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = i;
sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Add This line
```